# Soldering Path Optimisation - Python

Tags: python, optimization, path-finding

I'm trying to create a program that will determine the shortest possible total distance between multiple lines, incorporating the lines themselves. I previously made a program to do this but realised that calculating it with brute force is not realistic for any sizeable number of lines. The screenshot below should hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do. The black lines are path elements that need to be incorporated by the fastest path. The red line is the fastest route between them.

I've been messing around with making my own algorithms but I can't increase the program's capacity much beyond what is shown below. Does anyone have suggestions for a package that I should look into? I've seen a lot of talk about things like A* but by the looks of things I don't think it would quite suit this problem.

That said, I wondered about creating a kind of maze where straight soldered lines are made up of three points and are enclosed by obstacles, such that the only way to solder them would be also go through the other two points. But, this would still involve multiple destinations, which I don't think A* is quite right for.

From this perspective it looks a bit more like the travelling salesman problem but, answers to that question that I have seen do not incorporate the need to pass through certain routes.

As you can see from the image, I have made approaches based on brute force, nearest neighbour (which doesn't solve the problem very well) and have tried to develop a probabilistic method, but it is still very limited.

[image]

Comment: I assume the black arcs are required to be traversed. Is there a given direction, or can we traverse in either direction?

Comment: Hi Erwin, that's correct. They can be traversed in either direction but they have to be completed in one motion, i.e., you can't complete half the line, move off to another area then come back and complete the other half.